# Oracle decode function not working for date

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

The query does not give correct result. I am giving submit date between 01-Dec-14 to 30-Dec-14 but getting result for Nov.

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.id,
                pg.name,
                pt.name,
                PP.company_name,
                PP.code,
                O.order_number,
                O.status,
                O.submit_date,
                O.approval_date
FROM   orders O,
       partnerprofile PP,
       partnertype pt,
       partnergroup pg
WHERE  PP.id = O.to_partner_id
       AND Pp.type_id (+) = 8
       AND o.ordering_ratio_flag = Decode('NO', 'YES', '1',
                                                'NO', '0')
       AND pp.group_id = pg.id
       AND Pp.type_id(+) = Pt.id
       AND Decode(NULL, NULL, '1',
                        Pp.code) = Decode(NULL, NULL, '1',
                                                NULL)
       AND submit_date BETWEEN Decode('01-Dec-14', NULL, ( '01-JAN-01' ),
                                                   '01-Dec-14') AND
                                   Decode('30-Dec-14', NULL, ( '01-JAN-01' ),
                                                       '30-Dec-14')
       AND approval_date BETWEEN Decode(p_approved_from, NULL, ( '01-JAN-01' ),
                                                         p_approved_from) AND
                                 Decode(
                                     p_approved_to, NULL, ( '01-JAN-01' ),
                                                    p_approved_to
                                                                              )
       AND Decode(p_status, NULL, '1',
                            O.status) = Decode(p_status, NULL, '1',
                                                         p_status)
ORDER  BY O.id;
```

Comment: Add a explicit `DATE` format to your string. using `TO_DATE('01-JAN-01' ,'DD-MON-RR')`. Because Oracle's implicit format went wrong for you.

Comment: Or use ANSI DATE literals `date '2014-12-01'` or `date '2001-01-01'` (less typing than a proper `to_date()` call). Never rely on implicit data type conversion - especially not when with localized month names.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but you can't `DECODE` the value of NULL, since NULL is a fixed value.

Comment: I think you need this code, but you need to review your dates as the second says between date A and date B, but both are the same : AND Pp.code = '1'
AND submit_date    BETWEEN Decode(submit_date , NULL,to_date('01-Dec-14','dd-MON-yy'),submit_date)           AND Decode(submit_date,NULL,to_date('30-Dec-14','dd-MON-yy'),submit_date)
AND approval_date  BETWEEN Decode(p_approved_from, NULL, to_date('01-JAN-01','dd-MON-yy'),p_approved_from)   AND Decode(p_approved_to,NULL,to_date('01-JAN-01','dd-MON-yy'),p_approved_to)
AND p_status= 1

Comment: '01-jan-01' and p_approved_to are probably different data types (as I assume p_approved_to is a DATE type). So, in the best case, he's doing an implicit conversion, but you should not use implicit conversions if you can have explicit ones. If you use implicits at command line, fine. But not in code.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comment concering allways to use `to_date`/datefunctions if you indeed have date-data-types your using of decode doesn't make sense:

```
Decode('01-Dec-14', NULL, ( '01-JAN-01' ), '01-Dec-14') 
--this is always (!) '01-Dec-14'
```

Decode "if then else " works like this:

```
SELECT product_id,
       DECODE (warehouse_id, 1, 'Southlake', 
                             2, 'San Francisco', 
                             3, 'New Jersey', 
                             4, 'Seattle',
                                'Non domestic') 
       "Location of inventory" FROM inventories
       WHERE product_id < 1775;
```

This example decodes the value warehouse_id. If warehouse_id is 1, then the function returns 'Southlake'; if warehouse_id is 2, then it returns 'San Francisco'; and so forth. If warehouse_id is not 1, 2, 3, or 4, then the function returns 'Non domestic'.

( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm )

In your case you always check against the fixed value `'01-Dec-14'`, as this is not `null` the else case `'01-Dec-14'` is returned.